# Android: Synchronize Chronometer with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, chronometer

I'm using SeekBar in my application and when user seeks it should reset teh chronometer apporpriately.

I wrote the code as below.

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.setBase((mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
```

but it didn't help. chronometer shows like 2:48:00, which is very big and unrealistic for a 2:00 file.

Can someone help me with this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you comment the second line and tell me what happens

Comment: I remember updating a comment below, but now its not working.. :( here it vanished :O anyway after udpating as u said the counter goes as this 00:0) and 00:0* i dont knw the problem. I tried to change as u said and some other ways too it didn't work. Any clue plz.

Comment: i have updated my answer. try this. my day is almost over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

and tell me what happens.

Comment: The true Savior is the forgiver of your SINS and not me. ;)